# Encrypt connection string credentials from Web.config to ConnectionStrings.config

Tags: configuration, mvc

I need to move secret credential values from `Web.config` to `ConnectionStrings.config` in baseline folder, how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what it looks like in the web config?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: <add key="HostUrl" value=" " />
  <add key="ClientId" value="" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value=" " />
    <add key="ClientTimeout" value="" />
    <add key="ReturnUrl" value="" />
    <add key="UserSSO" value="true" />

Comment: AppSettings do not usually go in the connectionstrings file/section. I assume you are doing this since you want to encrypt the value? You can split the AppSettings into a separate file/additional file and then try to encrypt that. Also, update your question to provide enough detail to provifde answer, rather than everyone trying to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Yes I wan to encrypt values to connection strings config on my server

Comment: I think you need to update your question and add the details there.

Comment: try this method
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-encrypt-a-appsettings-key-in-webconfig